# matching code using preg match all

Tags: php, preg-match-all

i am coding a php for matching Code ussing  preg match all tag.

here is my php code.

```
  preg_match_all('|SentSmsId(\d*?)&noOfMessages|i', $data, $code);
```

echo "$code";

here is the html code.

```
<a href="sentSms.php?zxcoiesesscd=&SentSmsId=8830978&NoOfMessages=" style="text-decoration:none;"
```

I want to matching the sentsmsid code and echo it.

but does not working.

whats wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `=` in your regex,

```
preg_match_all('|SentSmsId=(\d*?)&noOfMessages|i', $data, $code);
print_r($code);
```

**[Working Demo.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Udncg3)**

Comment: Thanks... I Missed It... :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to take account of the =

e.g. SentSmsId\=(\d*?)&noOfMessages

Answer (score 0):

This is when you have several codes contained in $data:

```
preg_match_all('~SentSmsId=\K\d++(?=&noOfMessages)~', $data, $codes);

print_r($codes);
```

But if, you are looking for only 1 code, you must better use preg_match instead.